# Array Formula and Concatenate

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

I need to combine some columns from Google Sheet, populated by a Google Form.

I currently have the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(concatenate(F2:K2 &char(10)))
```

The above formula works, but I have to copy down the formula every time I get a new Google Form entry. I would like for the formula to be automatically copied down every time there is a new entry in the Google Form.

I it important for every column to be on its own line within the cell that I have the concatenate formula.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try in row 2:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 SUBSTITUTE(F2:K, " ", "♂")),,9^9))), " ", CHAR(10)), "♂", " "))
```

Comment: I'll admit, this formula is a little over my head. But, it did exactly what I needed it to!!! Much Thanks